# Accidently wiped out Windows 8 installation, now cant install windows 8 from USB

Tags: boot, usb, windows-8

I've installed ubuntu 14.04 in my machine and accidently wiped out all the windows related date, now the hard disk is showing as a one big partition,

Then I tried to create a bootable USB drive and when booting from the pen Im getting the following error. "The Selected Boot Device failed"

I tried Boot Repair and tried to boot from USB, still getting the above error.

Any help is highly appreciated. Laptop model is HP Envy 360.

Comment: The drive you are booting to has the required EFI drivers on it?

Comment: Didnt get your question. You mean efi drivers on USB or the HDD?...

Comment: They should exist on both, but since your asking about the Windows 8 USB installation drive, verify the required EFI drivers, are on the drive.

Comment: How did you create that boot drive?

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean by EFI drivers? I know UEFI have drivers but aren't those built into the firmware? "It needs to load a driver from a drive that needs the driver to get opened" doesn't sound making sense either.

Comment: In order for a drive to be bootable, in UEFI mode it must contain EFI  drivers, on a partition.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths I created using WinUSB in ubuntu. And also tried with tool provided by microsoft.

Comment: @Ramhound you mean the executable/binary (with "fallback name" as `bootx64.efi` / `bootia32.efi`) that replaces MBR boot code?

Answer (score 0):

I've disabled secure boot and enabled legacy boot from BIOS and was able to boot from the USB drive to install Windows 8 back again.
Thanks again for everyone who helped.